# Compass 0.12.7 Sprites Generated Multiple Times

Tags: sass, compass-sass, sprite

I just upgraded to Compass 0.12.7 however I noticed the the compilation time has increased dramatically especially when using the --force.

I noticed the the sprite files are being created multiple times as shown below;

```
create media/skin/promotions/new/sprite-s54cf4e80b1.png
create media/skin/promotions/new/sprite-s54cf4e80b1.png
create media/skin/promotions/new/sprite-s54cf4e80b1.png
create media/skin/promotions/new/sprite-s54cf4e80b1.png
```

**SASS Code**

```
$promotions-sprite: sprite-map("media/skin/promotions/new/*.png", $spacing: 18px);

&.icon0 { background: sprite($promotions-sprite, icon-0, 0px, 9px) no-repeat; }
&.icon1 { background: sprite($promotions-sprite, icon-1, 0px, 9px) no-repeat; }
```

Did anyone find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the following command to compile;

```
compass compile --force
```

Use these;

```
compass clean
compass compile
```